# Haskell interpretation of lambda function

Tags: function, haskell, lambda, notation

i have one Haskell function, which i don't understand but want to.

```
 i :: Int
 i = ((\g x -> g x + g x) (\y -> y)) 3
```

I know what a lambda function is: a nameless function.
E.g. `(\x -> x) 3` takes 3 and returns it, `(\x y -> x+y) 3 4` takes 3, 4 and returns 7. 
But in this special case i can't interpret it. I hope you can help me.
Btw. the solution for this function is 6.

Answer (score 6):

Now your `(\y -> y)` function is equivalent to `id`. Let's rewrite your function using that:

```
i = ((\g x -> g x + g x) id) 3
```

Now apply the `id` function to `(\g x -> g x + g x)`. This will get reduced to:

```
i = (\x -> id x + id x) 3
```

Now it's simple:

```
i = id 3 + id 3
i = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

`(\g x -> g x + g x)` takes the arguments `g`, which must be a function, and `x`, which must be a valid argument to that function, and then adds the result of applying `g` to `x` to itself.

In this case `\y -> y` is supplied as the value for `g` and `3` as the value for `x`, so we get `(\y -> y) 3 + (\y -> y) 3`. `(y -> y) 3` is `3`, so we get `3 + 3`, which is `6`.